# Making CSS Sprites Responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-sprites, fluid-layout

UPDATE 2:  Making further progress.  Almost there!

jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/Tfemm/6/

The sprite is now 99% responsive, except that the

```
margin-bottom:  %
```

Does not line up perfectly as the page changes width.  The

```
margin-left:    %
```

Seems to work great.

Any thoughts on how to align the margin-bottom perfectly?

UPDATE:  Making progress, but still not yet there.

Below is the jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/Tfemm/5/

The sprite image that I wanted to crop is working responsively, except it is only being cropped horizontally and not vertically.

The Code below:

```
<div class="responsive-sprite" style="width: 100%;">  
<img alt="Yay for alt tags..." src="http://zx85.dyndns.org/raphtest/img/nav-buttons2.jpg" />  
</div> 

img {  
 width: 100%;  
 height: 200%;
 margin-left: -81.869%;  
}  
.responsive-sprite {  
 overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Can anyone think of a way to crop this vertically as well?

### Below is the original post:

Is there a way to make CSS sprites responsive?

Take a look at the attached jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/Tfemm/2/

Is there a way to resize this CSS sprite once the container can no longer fit the full size image?

```
<div class="container">

    <h2 class="popular"><img src="http://zx85.dyndns.org/raphtest/img/nav-buttons2.jpg" alt="" />Featured</h2>

</div>




.container {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 128px;
    width: 192px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
h2 img {
  position: relative;
}
h2.popular img {
  top: 0;
  left: -867px;
}
h2.popular img:hover {
  top: -128px;
  left: -867px;
}
```

Comment: in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/Tfemm/6/   how to get the third last image (where u can see person hand)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. Tricky.

I haven't tested but would it work to orient the sprite horizontally instead of vertically and then:

```
h2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 192px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

h2 img {
    position: relative;
    width: 200%;
}

h2.popular img {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

h2.popular:hover img {
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
}
```

### Edit:

Seems to work, the sprite just needs to be configured. Have a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsundy/Tfemm/3/).

Unfortunately, I think you will have to do each button individually because the image height is what determines the button height when it is resized.

Comment: What works is the window that is over the image changes which shows more or less of the entire sprite, but it is not able to select the cropped sprite by itself without.

Comment: Take a look at some updates of mine.  It is very, very close to a solution but I am missing something.  Let me know what you think!

Comment: Unfortunately I think your problem is always going to be the height. There isn't a way (without javascript) to keep the proper ratio. That's why I was letting the image do the work for the height.

Comment: Why is that?  If the width works perfectly, why wouldn't the height be possible?

Comment: Because the percentage is calculated relative to the container. The container width is changing but the height isn't.

Comment: Ahh... Thanks for that.  +1.  The search continues!